# What does a comma at the end of a loop mean?

Tags: python, loops

I saw this code in the discussion section of leetcode. I don't really understand what the meaning of the comma at the end of the loop is.

```
def wallsAndGates(self, rooms):
    q = [(i, j) for i, row in enumerate(rooms) for j, r in enumerate(row) if not r]
    for i, j in q:
        for I, J in (i+1, j), (i-1, j), (i, j+1), (i, j-1):
            if 0 <= I < len(rooms) and 0 <= J < len(rooms[0]) and rooms[I][J] > 2**30:
                rooms[I][J] = rooms[i][j] + 1
                q += (I, J),
```

Comment: It makes it a tuple containing a single tuple... did you try checking for yourself on a repl? Anyway, it seems like a bad way of doing `q.append((I,J))`

Comment: And if I'm not wrong, invalid because you cannot concatenate a tuple and a list.

Comment: @COLDSPEED no it's not invalid because it works. Actually it seems to work with any iterable on the right side of `+=`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it works. Augmented "+" assignment works just like `some_list.extend(some_iterable)`

Answer (score 1):

The trailing comma makes it a tuple of tuples:

```
>>> (1, 2)  # how you normally see tuples
(1, 2)
>>> 1, 2    # but the parenthesis aren't really needed
(1, 2)
>>> 1,      # bare comma makes this a tuple
(1,)
>>>         # parenthesis separate the inner tuple from the trailing comma
>>> (1, 2), # giving a tuple of tuples
((1, 2),)
```

`q += (I, J),` is quite awkward and creates an extra unneeded tuple.

The code would have been better expressed as

```
q.append((I, J))
```

Interestingly it cannot be written as

```
q += (I, J) # no trailing comma works differently!
```

because it would have been equivalent to

```
q.extend((I, J)) # extend, not append!  "I" and "J" no longer grouped in a tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma makes (I,J) part of another tuple. It's the equivalent of ((I,J),)